# Possible to use two tape drives alternately with tar?

Tags: tar, tape, lto, library

I have a two drive, 24 slot LTO library.  I am testing the use of a script on the tar command  "--new-volume-script=COMMAND" that when called, contains the changer "mtx -f /dev/sg2 next" command to load the next tape. Ideally, I would like to have the next tape loaded in the 2nd drive so tar would switch to it immediately. Is this possible?  Maybe adding another -f option?

It's not unusual to hit enter twice when changing tapes and that causes tar to overwrite the next tape. Switching between drives would eliminate this potential error.

If I could get tar to switch drives, I could then figure out a way to load the next tape asynchronously in the full drive (while tar is writing to the 2nd drive) so that when the 2nd tape is filled the first has been replaced and so on.  I  would have to kick off a job that returns immediately so tar doesn't wait for the drive change to complete.

thanks

Jerry

Answer (score 1):

Point tar at a symlink to the tape device and have the "COMMAND" swap the symlink point to the other device.  (or you could go all out and call `mknod` from the script)

Comment: thanks, symlink is an interesting idea.  I'll test it.  Then I just need to figure out a way to kickoff a job that swaps the tape so the main thread doesn't have to wait.

Comment: perhaps use the non-rewinding tape device with tar and have the script kick off  a background rewind

Comment: When the LTO tape hits the end, it will rewind.  Then I switch to the other drive using symlink, I guess.  I wonder if symlink is re-evaluated again during a tar job,  but that is the test.   Then I need to kickoff a command that unloads the full tape and loads the next.  I cant do that in the mainline as tar will sit and wait. It has to be done in the background.  But it's all easy to test as you use the tar tape length and only write 1Meg to the tape before if fills.  Thanks for the input, I need to figure out how to do a background job too.  That should be easy.